# WPF Datagrid Colum ActualWidth incorrect - Wait for ObservableCollection to finish update

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn, actualwidth

I´m kind of stuck here with a little problem. I´ve got a DataGrid whose ItemSource is fed by an ObservableCollection. (I´m creating a little plugin for Revit).

My ObservableCollection contains of some Elements which are created when doing a selection in Revit. It is my goal to create a Stackpanel with Textboxes, which do have the same height as the actualized Columnwidths, which are set to Auto.

When running the code in "normal" speed I get a result like this:
[image]

When I debug the whole process it runs slower and I get a result like this (Which I want to get without debug mode):
[image]

```
popup.DataGridSelectedObjects.UpdateLayout();
popup.DataGridSelectedObjects.Items.Refresh();
Thread.Sleep(2000)

public void AddRegexItemToStackpanel(string parameterName, DataGridColumn dc)
{
    TextBox printTextBlock = new TextBox();
    printTextBlock.Width = dc.ActualWidth;
    printTextBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0.5, 0, 0, 0);
    printTextBlock.Name = dc.Header.ToString().Replace("__", "_");

    StackRegexPanel.Children.Add(printTextBlock);
}
```

Is there any method to wait the Observablecollection to update properly?

Thanks a lot and kind regards,
Jannis

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different approach. Using data binding should be the most intuitive. Avoiding XAML where XAML is possible will make life a lot harder most of the time and your code will start to smell.

Your `Thread.Sleep` looks very very suspicious too. It's also very likely that calling `UpdateLayout()` and `Items.Refresh()` should be avoided to improve the performance.

Changing the data source (`ObservableCollection`) will already trigger a refresh and, if necessary, a complete layout pass. No need to trigger both a second time. It will only make your UI slow.

Below you find two examples: a static, hard-coded version and a more elegant and dynamic version (where text boxes are added automatically to match the column count).
Both examples will automatically adjust the width of each `TextBox` if columns are resized (as a bonus when using data binding). The examples also highlight the efficiency of data binding in WPF. Code will always become smelly and overly complex when avoiding data binding and XAML.

To make a `TextBox` to follow the width of its respective column, simply use data binding:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=Table, Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth}"
           Margin="0.5,0,0,0" />
  <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=Table, Path=Columns[1].ActualWidth}"
           Margin="0.5,0,0,0" />
  <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=Table, Path=Columns[2].ActualWidth}" 
           Margin="0.5,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>

<DataGrid x:Name="Table" />
```

And to make it dynamic, simply use an `ItemsControl` that is configured to display its items horizontally:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Table, Path=Columns}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataGridColumn}">
      <TextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth}"
               Margin="0.5,0,0,0" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<DataGrid x:Name="Table" />
```

In both cases you should implement an `IValueConverter` to convert from `double` to `Thickness` (for the `Margin`) and bind the `StackPanel.Margin` of the first example or the `ItemsControl.Margin` of the second example to the `DataGrid.RowHeaderActualWidth` property to adjust for the row header (to align the text boxes properly).

---

Because you have provided more information, I felt the need to either delete or adjust my answer:

To dynamically change column count, you should always use a `DataTable` as data source. I have added an extension method that converts a collection to a `DataTable`, in case you need it.

Since the `TextBox` elements are meant to filter based on their associated column, I would suggest to modify the `DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle` to add a `TextBox` to the column header. This will be more convenient as  the `TextBox` will now automatically resize and move (in case the column is dragged).

The column's `TextBox` will bind to a `ObservableCollection` of `string` values (filter expressions), where the index of each item maps directly to a column index. Handling the `ColectionChanged` event allows to handle the `TextBox` input.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{public ObservableCollection<string> FilterExpressions
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(FilterExpressionsProperty);
    set => SetValue(FilterExpressionsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterExpressionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FilterExpressions", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public DataTable DataSource
  {
    get => (DataTable)GetValue(DataSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DataSource", 
    typeof(DataTable), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  // Example data models to show 
  // how to convert the collection to a DataTable
  private List<User> Users { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.FilterExpressions = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    this.FilterExpressions.CollectionChanged += OnFilterExpressionsChanged;
      
    this.Users = new List<User>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 500; index++)
    {
      this.Users.Add(new User());
    }

    this.DataSource = this.Users.ToDataTable();
  }

  private void OnFilterExpressionsChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    string changedFilterExpression = e.NewItems.Cast<string>().First();
    int columnIndexOfchangedFilterExpression = e.NewStartingIndex;

    // TODO::Handle filter expressions
  }

  // Example on how to modify the column count
  private void AddColumnToDataTable()
  {
    // If only using a DataTable
    this.DataSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column name", typeof(string)));

    // If underlying data source is a collection, then
    // add new data models and call extension method ToDataTable
    var newItemsWithAdditionalProperties = new List<object>();
    this.DataSource = newItemsWithAdditionalProperties.ToDataTable();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Example to show how to modify the column header to add a `TextBox` and how to use the attached behavior. The `DataGrid` now binds to a `DataTable` in order to allow to add/remove columns dynamically.

```xml
<Window>
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataSource}"
            local:DataGridColumnFilter.FilterValues="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=FilterExpressions}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle"
              TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="8" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor"
                Value="SizeWE" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
              <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="columnHeaderBorder"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="3,0,3,0">
                  <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                          StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="LightGray"
                                    Offset="0" />
                      <GradientStop Color="DarkGray"
                                    Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.BorderBrush>
                  <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                          StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="wHITE"
                                    Offset="0" />
                      <GradientStop Color="SkyBlue"
                                    Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.Background>
                  <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_FilterInput"
                              Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
          <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                  StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="White"
                            Offset="0" />
              <GradientStop Color="DeepSkyBlue"
                            Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

**DataGridColumnFilter.cs**
Attached behavior to map the `TextBox` elements of the column headers to a collection (data source) - direction is one way and update is send on `TextBox.LostFocus`.

My recommendation is to extend `DataGrid` to get rid of this attached behavior and to add more convenience to the control handling.

If filtering is only view related (which is usually the case) i.e. you don't intend to modify the data source based on the filtering, I recommend to move the filtering logic to the attached behavior (or extended `DataGrid`). This will keep your models clean.

```cs
public class DataGridColumnFilter : DependencyObject
{
  public static IList<string> GetFilterValues(DependencyObject obj) => (IList<string>)obj.GetValue(FilterValuesProperty);
  public static void SetFilterValues(DependencyObject obj, IList<string> value) => obj.SetValue(FilterValuesProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FilterValues",
    typeof(IList<string>),
    typeof(DataGridColumnFilter),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IList<string>), OnFilterValuesChanged));

  private static Dictionary<TextBox, int> GetIndexMap(DependencyObject obj) => (Dictionary<TextBox, int>)obj.GetValue(IndexMapProperty);
  private static void SetIndexMap(DependencyObject obj, Dictionary<TextBox, int> value) => obj.SetValue(IndexMapProperty, value);

  private static readonly DependencyProperty IndexMapProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IndexMap",
    typeof(Dictionary<TextBox, int>),
    typeof(DataGridColumnFilter),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  private static Dictionary<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter, DataGrid> DataGridMap { get; } = new Dictionary<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter, DataGrid>();

  private static void OnFilterValuesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (d is not DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (!dataGrid.IsLoaded)
    {
      dataGrid.Loaded += OnDataGridColumnsGenerated;
    }
    else
    {
      Initialize(dataGrid);
    }
  }

  private static void OnDataGridColumnsGenerated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    Initialize(dataGrid);
  }

  private static void Initialize(DataGrid dataGrid)
  {
    DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter headerPresenter = dataGrid.FindVisualChildren<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>().First();
    DataGridMap.TryAdd(headerPresenter, dataGrid);
    headerPresenter.AddHandler(UIElement.LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnTextBoxLostFocus));
    DataGridCellsPanel cellsPanel = headerPresenter.FindVisualChildren<DataGridCellsPanel>().First();
    IEnumerable<TextBox> inputFields = cellsPanel.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>();
    RegisterColumnHeaderTextBoxes(dataGrid, inputFields);
  }

  private static void RegisterColumnHeaderTextBoxes(DataGrid dataGrid, IEnumerable<TextBox> inputFields)
  {
    var indexMap = new Dictionary<TextBox, int>();
    SetIndexMap(dataGrid, indexMap);
    for (int index = 0; index < inputFields.Count(); index++)
    {
      TextBox inputField = inputFields.ElementAt(index);
      indexMap.Add(inputField, index);
    }
  }

  private static void OnTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.OriginalSource is not TextBox textInputField)
    {
      return;
    }

    var headerPresenter = sender as DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter;
    if (!DataGridMap.TryGetValue(headerPresenter, out DataGrid host))
    {
      return;
    }

    IList<string> filterExpressionSource = GetFilterValues(host);
    Dictionary<TextBox, int> indexMap = GetIndexMap(host);
    int columnIndex = indexMap[textInputField];

    // Preload source collection if empty
    if (columnIndex >= filterExpressionSource.Count)
    {
      for (int index = filterExpressionSource.Count; index <= columnIndex; index++)
      {
        filterExpressionSource.Add(string.Empty);
      }
    }

    UpdateFilterExpressionSource(textInputField, filterExpressionSource, columnIndex);
  }

  private static void UpdateFilterExpressionSource(TextBox textInputField, IList<string> filterExpressionSource, int columnIndex)
  {
    if (!filterExpressionSource[columnIndex].Equals(textInputField.Text, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
      filterExpressionSource[columnIndex] = textInputField.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

**ExtensionMethods.cs**
Extension method to convert a `IEnumerable<TData>` to a `DataTable`.

```cs
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static DataTable ToDataTable<TData>(this IEnumerable<TData> source)
  {
    Type dataType = typeof(TData);
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> publicPropertyInfos = dataType.GetProperties()
      .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreAttribute>() is null);
    var result = new DataTable();
    var columnNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo publicPropertyInfo in publicPropertyInfos)
    {
      DataColumn newColumn = result.Columns.Add(publicPropertyInfo.Name, publicPropertyInfo.PropertyType);

      System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute displayNameAttribute = publicPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute>();
      if (displayNameAttribute is not null)
      {
        newColumn.ColumnName = displayNameAttribute.DisplayName;
      }

      columnNameMapping.Add(publicPropertyInfo.Name, newColumn.ColumnName);
    }

    foreach (TData rowData in source)
    {
      DataRow newRow = result.NewRow();
      result.Rows.Add(newRow);
      foreach (PropertyInfo publicPropertyInfo in publicPropertyInfos)
      {
        object? columnValue = publicPropertyInfo.GetValue(rowData);
        string columnName = columnNameMapping[publicPropertyInfo.Name];
        newRow[columnName] = columnValue;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

**User.cs**
The data model used to create the `DataTable` from in the above example (*MainWindow.xaml.cs*).
The class also gives an example on how to use the attributes `IgnoreAttribute` to control
the visibility of properties/columns and `System.ComponentModel.DisplayName` to rename the property/column.

```cs
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  // Assign new column name for this property
  [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Mail address")]
  public string UserMail { get; set; }

  // Don't add this property as column to the DataTable
  [Ignore]
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**IgnoreAttribute.cs**

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false)]
public class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: Hi BionicCode, first of all. Thanks a lot for your help. This works great in XAML. The problem I am having now it the implementation of a "flexible" workflow. I add and delete columns to and from my datagrid by a listbox. 
For this reason I kind of need to add the TextBoxes via Code. 
How do I add the path to my binding?
System.Windows.Data.Binding myBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("DataGridSelectedObjects");
                myBinding.ElementName = "DataGridSelectedObjects";
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridSelectedObjects.Columns[i].ActualWidth);

Comment: If you use the second solution that utilizes an ItemsControl to display the text boxes, a TextBox is automatically created/removed for every column that you add/remove. It's a fully dynamic solution.

Comment: I guess I can't convince you to not create the elements manually. You seemed to be kind of obsessed to use C# instead of XAML to build your GUI. In this case you would have to fix the PropertyPath: `new PropertyPath($"Columns[{i}].ActualWidth")`.

Comment: Actually, I really fell in love with your dynamic solution, BUT I did not figure out a way to get all TextBox.Texts within the ItemsControl. When the TextChanged Event occures in one Textbox I need ALL TextValues. When getting into the ItemsControl container, I only got the Columns from my datagrid :(

Comment: What is the purpose of those text boxes?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about your scenario. Since your data source is a collection, your table must have a fixed column count. Is this the case? If not how do you add/remove columns then?

Comment: I use the upper textboxes to filter my observable collection with Regex. I can input an Regex into every Textbox. This Regex filters the columnvalues. Problem is, that I cannot just use the TextChanged event of the textbox alone, because if I remove the regex I have to loop through all "Regex-Fields" to see if the object will be visible again. 
I add and remove Columns by code ;) I created blank class parameters which are filled with values. These are bound to the columns by code and the header is changed by code.

Comment: I'm busy right now but I will suggest you s small solution jasper this evening. It's based on data binding the TextBox elements to a collection. But your columns are not dynamic in count right? You know the column county in advance? This would simplify the solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide you a complete example. Please add all relevant information to your question next time. This was not a nice experience, quite frankly. [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)